# Capture output of cmd, run remotely as another user on Windows

Tags: python, windows, powershell, automation, winrm

Trying to run a PowerShell script using WinRM

```
# $cred is valid and works for common PowerShell cmdlets

script = """
Start-Process ping.exe -Credential $cred -NoNewWindow -Wait -RedirectStandardOutput out.txt
Get-Content out.txt
"""
session = winrm.Session(host, auth=(user,passwd), transport="credssp')
result = s.run_ps(script)
```

If -Credentials is not used, the output is returned.

Otherwise, this creates an empty out.txt file. How do I redirect the output to out.txt/stdout?

Comment: Point of note: Your post title does not match what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this with PowerShell natively. It is a Windows proper security boundary. PowerShell will always run in the context of the user who ran the code.

To do this, you need to use an external tool, like [MS SysInternals PSExec](https://www.bing.com/search?q=run%20powershell%20code%20as%20a%20remote%20user%20psexec&form=ANNTH1&refig=a9bc98a725c8493baf41e0d4e90da0df&sp=-1&ghc=1&pq=run%20powershell%20code%20as%20a%20remote%20user%20psexec&sc=0-43&qs=n&sk=&cvid=a9bc98a725c8493baf41e0d4e90da0df)...

```
# Example:
# Using PsExec to Run Command on Remote Computer
psexec \\RemotePCName [-u username[-p password]] command [arguments]

psexec \\lon-srv01 powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -command "'{0:N2}' -f ((gci C:\PS | measure Length -Sum).Sum/1MB)"
```

... or use a scheduled task to run code at logon, or some other point in the day.

> [Don't use Credssp unless you have no other choice.](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20credssp%20accidental%20compromise&form=ANNTH1&refig=7307fe23a1094dd7939aee98451db004&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20credssp%20accidental%20compromis&sc=0-39&qs=n&sk=&cvid=7307fe23a1094dd7939aee98451db004)
>
> Accidental Sabotage: Beware of CredSSP:  https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/03/06/accidental-sabotage-beware-of-credssp/

[PowerShell redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection) is still tied to the user session. Yet, take a look at this Stackoverflow Q&A:

> [Redirect STDOUT\STDERR to current shell from win32_process create on remote computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687318/redirect-stdout-stderr-to-current-shell-from-win32-process-create-on-remote-comp)

Comment: Updated the title to reflect that the issue is capturing the cmd's output. Even when using psexec, I get command.exe exited with error code 0. The output is not redirected to text file.