# How to pass through a message through an RDP connection

Tags: windows, rdp, remoteapp

I've got a user running an application through the RDP / RemoteApp system.

I need to pass a message from a local app to another app running on the remote side. I control both of them completely. The message is a few bytes and I care about <1s latency. Completely async, there's no response.

How can I achieve that? I couldn't find any information about something like a custom side channel in RDP.

The options I know of are not great:

- monitoring file changes on a mapped drive - that would be really slow... not sure that's even guaranteed to be reliable over RDP
- fake USB/smartcard device redirect - that's a serious overkill and I really don't want to write drivers just for this

Is there anything much simpler? Ideally I'd love to just share a named pipe, but that doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is RDS Virtual Channel apparently - it allows creating separate streams to a server on the remote side.

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/terminal-services-virtual-channels

A universal network / named pipe tunneling example: https://github.com/earthquake/UniversalDVC

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the next solution fits your needs. Is not universal but useful thing.

You must have:

- enabled `Local drive redirection` on RDP-server;
- administrative rights on RDP-client PC;
- ability to use `named pipes` by your app.

Instruction:

1. On RDP connection redirect your drive. It would be `C:`
2. Make link to your pipe (with administrative rights). It would be file `abc` in `C:\pipe` folder. For working `named pipe` use same name to avoid mistakes:

   `mklink abc \\.\pipe\abc`
3. Create pipe `abc` by your app. You can also use external tools instead like Makepipe.exe or [Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096969/):

   `Makepipe /w 1 /pabc`
4. On remote RDP session use symlink file to work with `named pipe`. This cmd-command send text "Message" to RDP-client's `named pipe` by symbolic link.

   `echo Message \\tsclient\C\pipe\abc`

P.S. As you can see file system can be used for inter-process communication.